# Barcode decoding rotated codes - how to use zxing for Android

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want my app to scan barcodes and found zxing (https://github.com/zxing/zxing) as best open source library for it. 
If I use it standard intent way, it only detects and decodes when code is aligned with blinking guideline.

However, in java code it says e.g. in 
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/pdf417/detector/Detector.java

> "Encapsulates logic that can detect a PDF417 Code in an image, even if
>   the  * PDF417 Code is rotated or skewed, or partially obscured."
>
> "@param multiple if true, then the image is searched for multiple
>   codes."

So I guess Zxing library can be used to scan rotated images and decode multiple barcodes from one page. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use Barcode Scanner API in Google Play services:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html

Comment: thank you. good library. however, one of sample pdf417 codes zxing reads (and some other libraries too) Google library did not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

in order to read the barcode in any orientation, you need to add to your code

```
    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    Result result = new UPCAReader().decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this flag. It can find a Code 39 barcode rotated to about 45 degrees. But it cannot read a Code 39 barcode rotated between 45 and 135 degrees. This seems to only help 2D barcodes. ZXing has a bug for this: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/211